# best way to test a library

Tags: java, junit, automated-tests

I'm writing a java library which can be used to control Transmission(a torrent download client) remotely. Now I can add/start/stop/remove a torrent.
I've written some tests for it. But the problem is that every time I change some code, I should first run junit test to add a torrent to Transmission, then check whether the torrent is actually added to Transmission. Then I run the second test to stop the job, and check whether it is actually stopped and so on.
I want to know what is the best way to test the code in industry. Is it possible to run some tests and get a 100% passed without checking the Transmission status manually?

Comment: I wouldn't have tests relying on other tests. Your test `TestStoppingTransmission` would itself add a transmission, start it, stop it ,and assert the result. You can have set up, utility, and tear down code, etc. to make parts reusable and automated.

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils It's good idea to avoid tests relying on other tests, but sometimes we can't. For example, to test `AddTorrent`, I should call this function and then call the `GetTorrent` to check if it's really added in `TestAdd`. Now this test relies on `TestGet` because we should make sure `GetTorrent` works correctly. `TestGet` also relies on `AddTorrent` on the other hand.  So two tests rely on each other. I think the only way to test the functions is to open the Transmission itself and check the result manually.

Comment: You can always avoid relying on other tests by simply not relying on them. I understand what you're getting at but the fact remains you should be testing one unit of work per unit test. I suggest you do your best to avoid what you're trying to do.